# Easiet Way to Store Multi-line data from a Text Box

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a multi-line text box that users can input social media address. So my question is what is the best way that I store these so that I retrieve them and link each of them. Wouldn't each one need to be stored in its own row. (Basically I would create a table UserSocialMedia, then use a Foreign key to link it to the table and select it for that user when display it, then link each of them). Or is there a way that I can store them all in one row and retrieve them and then link them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split out the text into individual addresses and store each one individually in a table, or better yet, modify your UI to accept URLs via multiple single-line inputs.

If you stored them as a single entity you would need to do additional parsing in your client to add markup, they would be horrible/inefficient to search and again would need additional parsing (for example to pull a facebook URL from a clump of others).

Even better would be to identify the site; facebook/twitter/bebo etc from the submitted url, store a siteID and just retain the profile specific part.

Answer (score 0):

before saving the value to your Db, add something like this line to preserve line breaks:

```
var textToSave = txtMultiLine1.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />");
```

then normally save this value to your DB, when retrieving, you can just show it and they will be one after another in seperate lines :)

cheers!